# AmMap addLabel not working

Tags: jquery, amcharts, ammap

I am using below code for rendering a map when no data is available. The map is working fine when data comes. I tried serveral methods to add label but it's not working. The last two lines show what I've tried so far to add a label

```
// build map
AmCharts.ready(function () {
    AmCharts.theme = AmCharts.themes.dark;
    window.map = new AmCharts.AmMap();

    window.map.areasSettings = {
        unlistedAreasColor: "#000000",
        unlistedAreasAlpha: 0.1
    };
    window.map.imagesSettings.balloonText = "<span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[title]]</b>: [[value]]</span>";

    var dataProvider = {
        mapVar: AmCharts.maps.worldLow,
        images: []
    }

    // create circle for each country


    // it's better to use circle square to show difference between values, not a radius
    var maxSquare = maxBulletSize * maxBulletSize * 2 * Math.PI;
    var minSquare = minBulletSize * minBulletSize * 2 * Math.PI;

    // create circle for each country
    for (var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
        var dataItem = mapData[i];
        var value = dataItem.value;
        // calculate size of a bubble
        var square = (value - min) / (max - min) * (maxSquare - minSquare) + minSquare;
        if (square < minSquare) {
            square = minSquare;
        }
        var size = Math.sqrt(square / (Math.PI * 2));
        var id = dataItem.code;

        dataProvider.images.push({
            type: "circle",
            width: size,
            height: size,
            color: "#ff9a00",
            longitude: latlong[id].longitude,
            latitude: latlong[id].latitude,
            title: dataItem.name,
            value: value
        });
    }

    window.map.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    window.map.export = {
        enabled: true
    }
    window.map.projection = "winkel3";
    window.map.write("dash_chart_world");
});

// add label
AmCharts.AmMap.mapdiv.addLabel(0, '50%', 'You don\'t have any sales yet', 'center');

// set opacity of the chart div
AmCharts.AmMap.mapdiv.style.opacity = 0.5;
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you miss out is, that the function needs to be called whenever something happens to the chart. As your demands are coupled to the data we can add an event listener for [`dataUpdated`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmChart#dataUpdated) and check if the array of images is empty:

```
map.addListener("dataUpdated", function() {
    if (map.dataProvider.images.length == 0) {
        // add label
        map.addLabel(0, '50%', 'You don\'t have any sales yet', 'center');

        // set opacity of the chart div
        map.mapContainer.node.style.opacity = 0.1;
  }
});
```

Concerning the other changes I did:

- The method [`addLabel`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmChart#addLabel) belongs to an `AmChart` object and not to
  `AmCharts.AmMap.mapdiv`. (That's not even existing.)
- Changing the opacity of the `div` that holds the whole map (which can be get using `map.div` [`AmChart.div`]) would change the opacity of the added label aswell. If you only want to change the opacity of the map itself you can make the change on the `map.mapContainer.node` element. (This is the part of the `svg` holding the map projection.)

I prepared a small [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0b8ftja0/) where you can see it working with dynamic data.

Comment: Thanks @gerric, that was perfect. i had been able to show "no data found"  for my other line chart and donut chart but the AmMap was tricky.